# short Apache outages (VPS, ModSecurity)

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, http, mod-security

I have a problem with my site recently hosted at Liquidweb, none of their techs seems to be able to solve this issue even after days. Was hoping I could get some help here.

Occasionally, my site's HTTP will not respond - usually 2-3 times a day. It simply wouldn't load. And all the users will be unable to connect to the site for about 5 minutes. Google Analytics real time stats also show that users online drop from 200+ online to zero.

Apache works fine, it didn't restart or shutdown according to the logs. The errors present in the apache logs pointed out by the tech were:

```
[error] [client 169.199.175.224] ModSecurity: Error
reading request body: Connection reset by peer 
[error] [client 169.199.175.224] Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70014

[error] [client 54.234.74.100] client sent invalid
HTTP/0.9 request: HEAD HTTP/1.1 [Wed May 08 08:35:36 2013] [error] [client 173.218.197.87] Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70007
```

The tech said it could be a code issue, but I didn't have any problems while I was with Hostgator's shared hosting. Anyone knows from the error above if it could be a code issue? Or what could be causing this?

PCRE limitations has been set high, the INNODB buffer has been allocated way more memory and Apache max clients raised.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your application to DB connection and DB logs at time of error.